# Differentiability through paths

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}},& (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0,& (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}.$$
>   Show that $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$, however, show that for every differentiable path $\lambda: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, passing through origin, $f \circ \lambda$ is differentiable.

My problem is in the second part. If $\lambda: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a line pararallel to $e_{i}$ passing through $0$, 
$\lambda(t) = (0,0) + te_{i}$, I can show that $(f\circ \lambda)'(0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}f(0,0)$. I've tried to generalize this to an arbitrary path with domain $(0,1)$, but I couldnt. Can someone help me?

Comment: What does path-differentiable mean?There is the usual definition of the derivative as a linear transformation satisfying some condition, and differentiability meaning that the derivative exists.

Comment: It got badly written, I'll change it. It is only a path that is differentiable.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\lambda(t) = (\lambda_1(t), \lambda_2(t))$. Since $\lambda$ goes through the origin, we have that $\lambda(c) = (0,0)$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. We can assume that $\lambda'(c) \ne 0$ so that $\lambda$ isn't constant on a neighbourhood of the origin.

Then $(f\circ \lambda)(c) = 0$ so by definition:

$$(f\circ \lambda)'(c) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(f\circ \lambda)(c+t)- (f\circ \lambda)(c)}t = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(f\circ \lambda)(c+t)}t=  \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\lambda_1(c+t)^3}{t(\lambda_1(c+t)^2 + \lambda_2(c+t)^2)}$$

Notice that
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\lambda_1(c+t)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\lambda_1(c+t)-\lambda_1(c)}{t}= \lambda_1'(c)$$
and similarly for $\lambda_2$.

Therefore
$$(f\circ \lambda)'(c) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\lambda_1(c+t)^3}{t^3} \cdot \frac{t^2}{\lambda_1(c+t)^2 + \lambda_2(c+t)^2}=\lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{\lambda_1(c+t)}{t}\right)^3 \cdot \frac1{\left(\frac{\lambda_1(c+t)}{t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\lambda_2(c+t)}{t}\right)^2}$$

Since $\lambda'(c) \ne 0$, the product rule for limits yields $$(f\circ \lambda)'(c) = \frac{\lambda_1'(c)^3}{\lambda_1'(c)^2 + \lambda_2'(c)^2}$$

Comment: I would say, near the bottom, "Because $\lambda'(c) \ne 0$, the product rule for limits yields"

Comment: @JohnHughes Note that I already assumed that $\lambda'(c) \ne 0$ at the beginning

Comment: I did note that. I was making a suggestion about how one might present the material clearly to the OP, not on completeness of the argument. Right now, you make that assumption, but never mention it again in the proof, and the reader might wonder, "Why was that assumption there at all?" This is clearly a matter of taste. For the **right** reader, the proof might be reduced to "Any fool can plainly see that this is true" and be entirely adequate.

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok, you may be right, I added it in the answer. However, I'm not too happy with my argument why $\lambda'(c) \ne 0$ in the first place. Is there a clearer explanation why we should only consider paths with nonzero derivative at the origin?

Comment: Two arguments, I think: One is that the lemma I wrote (if $\alpha, \beta$ agree to first order at $t_0$, then $f\circ \alpha$ and $f \circ \beta$ have the same derivative at $t_0$, only holds when $\alpha'(t_0) \ne 0$ in general. But for this particular function $f$, if $\lambda(t_0) = (0,0)$ and $\lambda'(t_0) = 0$, then $(f\circ \lambda)'(t_0) = 0$ (which you can prove by computing limits pretty easily, I believe). So really the answer is: the zero-speed case is another case you should handle, but it's not too tough.

Comment: What helps a lot is a lemma that says that if $u'(0) = u''(0) = ... = u^{(k)}(0)$, then $u(t) = u(0) + t^{k+1} v(t)$, where $v(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I actually struggled to show your lemma so I asked a friend and he came up with this counterexample: consider $f(x,y) = |x|^{1/3}|y|^{1/6}$ and paths $\alpha(t) = (t,0)$, $\beta(t) = (t,t^2)$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ agree to first order at $0$. However, $f \circ \alpha \equiv 0$ so $(f \circ \alpha)'(0) = 0$ but $$(f \circ \beta)'(0) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{(f \circ \beta)(t,t^2)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{|t|^{2/3}}t$$
doesn't exist. I'm able to show it if we additionally assume that $f$ is locally Lipschitz around $0$ (which is satisfied if e.g. $f$ is differentiable at $0$).

Comment: Assume that $(f\circ \alpha)'(0)$ exists so $$|f(\alpha(t)) - f(\alpha(0)) - (f\circ \alpha)'(0)t| = o(t)$$ and $\|\alpha(t) - \alpha(0) - \alpha'(0)t\| = o(t), \|\beta(t) - \beta(0) - \beta'(0)t\| = o(t)$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ agree to first order at $0$ we get $$\|\alpha(t) - \beta(t)\| \le \|\alpha(t) - \alpha(0) - \alpha'(0)t\| + \|\beta(t) - \beta(0) - \beta'(0)t\|=o(t)$$ Then $\|f(\alpha(t)) 
- f(\beta(t))\| \le K\|\alpha(t) - \beta(t)\| = o(t)$ so

Comment: $$|f(\beta(t)) - f(\beta(0)) - (f\circ \alpha)'(0)t| \le |f(\alpha(t)) - f(\alpha(0)) - (f\circ \alpha)'(0)t| + \|f(\alpha(t)) 
- f(\beta(t))\| = o(t)$$
so $f\circ\beta$ is differentiable at $0$ and  $(f\circ \beta)'(0)=(f\circ \alpha)'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**A broad hint, but (deliberately) not a complete solution**

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two differentiable paths  with $\alpha(0) = \beta(0) = (0,0)$ and $\alpha'(0) = \beta'(0) \ne 0$. In short form, '$\alpha$ and $\beta$ agree to first order at $0$'.

You can prove that if $f \circ \alpha$ is differentiable at $0$, then so is $f \circ \beta$, and the derivatives agree. (I think I'd use an epsilon-delta argument to show this. The proof should not depend on $f$, by the way, but the assumption that the derivative $\alpha'(0)$ is nonzero will be essential.)

Once you know that, you need only consider a few possible curves through the origin, namely those of the form 
$$
\alpha(t) = t \mathbf{v}
$$
where $\mathbf{v} = (a, b) = r (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)
$
is some nonzero vector, i.e., $r \ne 0$. For each such vector, it's easy to write down $f \circ \alpha(t)$ and observe that it's differentiable, and then (with the help of the second paragraph) you're done.

Comment: Its a nice hint, John! I'll try to use it. Just a point: the domain of path not contains $0$ so, is it still possible to keep the same approach with some trick?

Comment: The domain of my paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both supposed to be some open interval containing $0$, such as $-1 < t < 1$ (or perhaps all of $\Bbb R$). For the particular path $\alpha$ that I chose ($\alpha(t) = t\mathbf{v}$), the domain might as well be all of $\Bbb R$, just as it was for your path $\lambda$. In short, I don't know what you're asking here, because we seem to be doing the same thing in general, except that instead of just considering the vertical and horizontal lines through the origin, I'm considering *all* lines through the origin.

Comment: Yes, I understood your idea. In fact, as I said, I was able to solve a very particular case considering $\mathbb{R}$. But the question asks for a path with domain $(0,1)$. Thus, at least my approach, doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Just replace my definition of $\alpha$ with $\alpha(t)  = (t - \frac12) \mathbf{v}$, and do all the computations at $t = \frac12$. (Away from $t = \frac12$, $f$ is everywhere differentiable so the chain rule shows things are nice. At $t = \frac12$, you have to use limits, etc.)