$f \in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and for all $g \in C^1([0, 1], \mathbb{R}^2)$ their composition is in $C^1$. Is $f$ necessarily in $C^1$?

A function $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is such that for any function $g \in C^1([0, 1],
> \mathbb{R}^2)$ their composition $f \circ g$ belongs to $C^1([0,1])$.
Prove or give a counter example that $f \in C^1 (\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Now here's my idea of the proof: if $f$ is not in $C^1 (\mathbb{R}^2)$, then there is a sequence of points for which the limit doesn't hold. Then I can consider such function $g$ that these points are in it's image, $f \circ g \in $C^1([0,1])$, hence the limit holds for these points too.
However this proof seems really informal, and i don't know how to formalize it (or if it is even correct). Please help!

The function from this question might be a good counterexample, as it is continuous (we can observe that $|x^3| = (x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq (x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$, so that $|f(x,y)| \leq |(x,y)|_2)$ thus continuous at the origin, and it was already continuous everywhere else) and differentiable along all paths, although continuous differentiability has not been established yet.

@BrunoB Would you mind sending me a link to the question you mentioned?

Oh I'm very sorry, I wrote the whole comment and then forgot the pivotal part... Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079497/1104384
